# Strapi Development mode issue

Tags: strapi

I am new to strapi and want to start it on development mode. Below are steps I have followed so far

```
git clone git@github.com:strapi/strapi.git
cd strapi
npm run setup
```

but then while generating a project somewhere else using the development mode: i am getting error on running below command as

> 'strapi' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable
>   program or batch file.

```
strapi new myDevProject --dev
```

any help? I have uninstalled strapi global as documentation pointed. Anything I am missing. Do I need to install non global version of strapi in the same directory.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds to me that you might need to setup your path to find Strapi. 
How to update your path is different depending on your operation system.
e.i. PATH=$PATH:/path/to/strapi/bin

Answer (score 6):

You can install Strapi globally in your machine using npm without the need of pulling the repo manually:

```
npm install -g strapi@beta
```

Restart your terminal, then run:

```
strapi new [project_name] --quickstart
```

Then your project will start automatically :)

Answer (score 6):

Putting npx before strapi will resolve this issue . So instead of strapi develop , run following command:

`npx strapi develop`

Answer (score 1):

After pull repository and install `strapi@beta` globally you need generate new project by command like in the bellow instructions:

> 1. [Create a new project](https://github.com/strapi/strapi#-create-a-new-project)
>
>    ```
>    strapi new my-project
>    ```
> 2. [Start your project](https://github.com/strapi/strapi#-start-your-project)
>
>    ```
>    cd my-project
>    strapi develop
>    ```

**Source:** https://github.com/strapi/strapi

I proposse you read [Quick Start Guide](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/getting-started/quick-start.html#_1-install-strapi-globally)

Answer (score 1):

For existing projects you are cloning on a different machine, just don't forget to:

```
npm install
```

Resolved

> 'strapi' is not recognized as an internal or external command

for me

Answer (score 1):

As the above answers you can install the `strapi-cli` globally, or once your project is created use below commands to run it

```
npm run build
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

please proceed the following steps:

step1 - open node.js command prompt and type -> npm install strapi@alpha g

step2 - strapi new (anyName_You_want_toGive) --quickstart

(remove the brackets)

it should look like

strapi new anyName_You_want_toGive --quickstart

thats all.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had already deployed my strapi app in development and successfully ran
`strapi develop`
but it didnt work for me in recent times.

This did though:

```
npm run dev
```

I was able to get the local strapi host running but I did get some npm errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just run command `npm run develop` for starting strapi application.

Also you can follow more steps on Documentation [here](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/quick-start)